# in perl, why does push cause a regex created by qr to be changed when not put into double quotes?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, push

I am defining regexes inside a script, using `qr`, and pushing them onto an array. But now it appears that if I do not put the regex inside double quotes, the action of pushing it onto the array changes it. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Data::Dumper::Concise;
my @regexes;
my $rgx = 'dog'; my $mdf = 'i';
$rgx = join ( '', '(?', $mdf, ')', $rgx ) if ($mdf); # in production, $mdf could be empty
eval { $rgx = qr/$rgx/ };
if ($@) # catch illegitimate regex modifier, such as 'g'
{
   die "rgx==$rgx; mdf==$mdf; qr throws an error";
}
push @regexes, $rgx;
push @regexes, "$rgx";
print "first try just printing \$rgx\n";
print " no double quotes:";
print $rgx; print "\n";
print "yes double quotes:";
print "$rgx"; print "\n";
print "but now see what happens when I push it onto an array\n";
print Dumper \@regexes;
```

What this produces:

```
first try just printing $rgx
 no double quotes:(?^:(?i)dog)
yes double quotes:(?^:(?i)dog)
but now see what happens when I push it onto an array
[
  qr/(?i)dog/i,
  "(?^:(?i)dog)"
]
```

I thought that `(?^:(?i)dog)` was a finished product, ready for a regex match, such as

```
if ( /$rgx/ )
```

and, in fact, that is why I run the prospective regex through `qr`.

Why does `push` change it?

And why does it produce the particular syntax,
`qr/(?i)dog/i`?

Comment: When you have a regex in a variable, you use it like `"foo" =~ $regex`. When you stringify it, it stops being a regex.

Comment: Do you understand following command `push @regexes, "$rgx";` -- particularly part "$rgx"?

Answer (score 5):

You are effectively asking the difference between the values returned by

```perl
my $rgx = qr/$rgx/; $rgx
```

and

```perl
my $rgx = qr/$rgx/; "$rgx"
```

`qr//` compiles the provided regex pattern and returns an object representing the compiled form. This is the value stored in the variable `$rgx`, and this is returned by the expression `$rgx`.

`""` builds a string, so `"$rgx"` provides the stringification of `$rgx`. This thankfully returns a string that can be used as a regex pattern represented by the compiled object. However, by doing `"$rgx"`, you are effectively undoing the work done by `qr/$rgx/`.

Data::Dumper represents regex objects using `qr//` literals and strings using the `""` literals.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same pattern in different representations. `Data::Dumper` makes a particular string representation of an object, and the regex object itself creates a different representation when you interpolate it.

Perhaps my article from *The Effective Perl* can help: [Let perl create your regex stringification](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/10/let-perl-create-your-regex-stringification/)

Comment: So it was not `push` that produced that effect, it was `Data::Dumper`. So the answer to my first question, "Why does `push` change it," is that it does **not** change it. But what is the point of having an `i` in 2 different places in the `Data::Dumper`  representation of the regex? Why repeat this flag?

Comment: Re "*it was Data::Dumper*", No, it was `"$rgx"`. DD just represented that change. /// Re "*Why repeat this flag?*", While effectively equivalent, `qr/(?i)dog/` would be more accurate than `qr/(?i)dog/i`.

Answer (score -1):

Since I am answering my own question, I can be slightly disrespectful toward the poster (myself). I asked two questions.

The answer to the first is: "Un-ask the question. `push` does **not** change the regex."

The answer to the second is: Again, `push` does not produce that particular syntax. The `Data::Dumper` package is what produces the puzzling syntax.
The following code demonstrates this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); use Data::Dumper::Concise;
my $rgx = 'dog';
my $mdf = 'is';
$rgx = join ( '', '(?', $mdf, ')', $rgx ) if ($mdf); # in production, $mdf could be empty
print "   no quotes rgx=="; print $rgx; print ";\n"; print "      quotes rgx=="; print "$rgx"; print ";\n";
print "DD no quotes rgx=="; print Dumper $rgx; print "DD    quotes rgx=="; print Dumper "$rgx"; 
$rgx = qr/$rgx/;
print "\nNow, after qr:\n";
print "   no quotes rgx=="; print $rgx; print ";\n"; print "      quotes rgx=="; print "$rgx"; print ";\n";
print "DD no quotes rgx=="; print Dumper $rgx; print "DD    quotes rgx=="; print Dumper "$rgx";
```

and what it prints:

```
   no quotes rgx==(?is)dog;
      quotes rgx==(?is)dog;
DD no quotes rgx=="(?is)dog"
DD    quotes rgx=="(?is)dog"

Now, after qr:
   no quotes rgx==(?^:(?is)dog);
      quotes rgx==(?^:(?is)dog);
DD no quotes rgx==qr/(?is)dog/si
DD    quotes rgx=="(?^:(?is)dog)"
```

It has been stated that `qr` "compiles" a regex. Because of my past experience as a student writing code in compiled languages (FORTRAN, Pascal), I think I misunderstood that term. From https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Scalar-values,

> Scalars aren't necessarily one thing or another. There's no place to declare a scalar variable to be of type "string", type "number", type "reference", or anything else. Because of the automatic conversion of scalars, operations that return scalars don't need to care (and in fact, cannot care) whether their caller is looking for a string, a number, or a reference. Perl is a contextually polymorphic language whose scalars can be strings, numbers, or references (which includes objects).

If I read this correctly, the output of `qr` will not be "binary" or something analogous to Pascal object code. It is exactly what `print` shows it to be in the sample code.

So I was way off-base by thinking that `push` was the guilty party. It appears that `Dumper` automatically converts certain scalars, if they happen to be interpretable as regexes, by putting them inside forward slashes. And also `Dumper` apparently copies the regex flag from inside the parentheses in the regex, reorders it (note it changed the double flag from `is` to `si`), and puts it after the 2nd forward slash.

Comment: Re "*If I read this correctly, the output of qr will not be "binary" or something analogous to Pascal object code.*", Well, it doesn't produce executable code, but it does produce a tree of instruction-like rules for the regex engine. To see an example, execute the following command: `perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/abc[de]|fgh|ijk.*lmn/'` As you can see, what's produced is not that far off from object code.

Comment: Re "*It is exactly what print shows it to be in the sample code.*", This is completely incorrect.

Comment: Re "*It appears that Dumper automatically converts certain scalars,*", Not certain scalars. Every single one value is converted. Printing out the computer's representation of a value would be completely unreadable. DD converts each value into a Perl code literal that produces the value in question. For example, the number two might result in `2`, a string consisting of the first three letters of the alphabet might result in `"abc"` and a regex object might result in `qr/.../`. None of those strings existed in memory before DD generated them.

Comment: The paragraph you quoted just says that scalars can contain different kinds of values. That has nothing to do with what qr// does.

Comment: The only part of this answer that is correct is that push has nothing to do with your question, which was made plenty apparent by an earlier answer.